# Finding Equivalent Resistance

Tags: resistance

The question asks to find the equivalent resistance of such a network of resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbiJLP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have managed to simplify it down to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM9Epd.png)</sup>

Is there a way to find the equivalent resistance without the use of a delta-transform (as I do not believe those are allowed on this assignment). From a logical point of view since the left and right nodes of the 0.5 ohm resistor are at the same voltage, no current would flow through it and hence it would offer no resistance. Would the equivalent resistance then be the parallel connection of the 1 and 1.5 ohm resistor? or am I completely wrong.

Thank you in advance for your responses!

Comment: It's correct: R3//short = short. But you shouldn't have wasted time in calculating the parallel of R6 and R7 - they are both shorted.

Comment: so the correct answer is 0.6 ohms = 3/5 ohms?

And thank you for your help :)

Comment: @FilipGajowniczek Yes, \$0.6\Omega\$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that in the original circuit the resistors R6 and R7 are short as they have a wire connecting their ends. You can just replace them with a short. Replacing it with a short you are left with R4 and R5 in parallel. It should be fairly easy to solve from here. It is

$$ R3 || (R2 + (R4 || R5)) = 0.6 \Omega $$.